# On speed - Why JSON if the data is simple? (not objects)

Tags: json, performance

Characters like { " take bytes when transporting to and from the server

This is faster:

```
var BENZ={
    enc:function(i){
        var s='';
        for(var v in i){
            s=(s==='')?v+'^'+i[v]:s+'¬'+v+'^'+i[v];
            }return s;
    },
    dec:function(p){
        var o={};
        p=p.split('¬');
        for(var n=0;n<p.length;n++){
            var k=p[n].split('^');
            var v=k[1];
            k=k[0];
            o[k]=(/^\d+$/.test(v))?parseInt(v):v;
            }return o;}
};

BENZ.enc({'my':'object','num':100});    // makes a string
BENZ.dec('my^object¬num^100');          // makes an object
```

The only problem is that afterward things like arrays have to be split (then if the parts are numbers then you have to parseInt() each)

is binary faster?

msgpack does something like this (less raw), What I don't get is that they hex encode everything which adds twice the bytes (turns each char into 2 digits)

Why do they do this?

With my way I am comparing types as a rule of thumb, for some strange reason this feels more productive.

What do you think?

Comment: Most successful protocols of internet were successful not because they were fast but because they were reliable and easy to use, extend, apply. Think about how verbose is HTML for example. JSON wasn't designed for compacity at all. Speed is attained because all parts are optimized for JSON and you'll get bigger gains by ensuring you do it right (do you at least gzip and handle caching ?).

Comment: yeah, my god lol I'm not a *complete* idiot :D

Comment: So, as you ensured you gzipped, how did your language compare to JSON after compression ? Do you really think it's worth the pain (and worth the fact the tooling available for future evolution is suddenly reduced) ?

Comment: I'm in thailand and my server is in england, I cant afford to get a mirror so no pain no game! Plus I kinda like typing my name for a function and I have seen speed increased quite a bit!

Comment: The primary issue with custom, "magic string" formatting is that it is not interoperable and is often not thoroughly designed or tested. Inter-platform serialization schemes are developed for standardized, predictable data exchange between platforms/services/processes/etc. No other platform knows how to use your magic-strings, and there may be many untested cases in which data inserted into your scheme does not come out properly on the other end.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by tooling? I am still allowed to use JSON when/if I need it... Plus i'm worried now, I am just coding, I din't think I was responsible for evolution!? Maybe shouldn't have stood on that ant...

Comment: All that said, perhaps your scheme is better after all, and you could find a working group to help ensure portability and reliability and to promote its use.

Comment: Thanks for the encoragement. it's not better. Compared to the depth and ability of JSON it's crappy but Its fast. If you don't want to transport objects it's is fine but if you need them use JSON